# How can I select the middle of three elements?

Tags: css, jquery

I have three `<li>` tags in an `<ul id="accordion">`. I now want to select the various items via jQuery.

To select the first `<li>` item, we can use `$("#accordion li:first")`.

To select the last `<li>` item, `$("#accordion li:last")` works

How can I select the middle `<li>` element through a jQuery selector? There is no `:middle` pseudo-class that I could use here.

Comment: Try reading the documentation: See http://api.jquery.com/eq/ and http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Answer (score 4):

You can combine two ":not" selectors so that you get all of the 'not first, and not last' elements like so:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)').css('color', 'red');
```

Also, check the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ronency/hhmktkLu/)

Answer (score 3):

There is no `:middle` selector, and this makes sense – what element would get matched when we have 4 items?
However, you can access elements by their index. Using CSS Level 3 selectors, you can use the `:nth-child(…)` pseudo-class:

```css
#accordion li:nth-child(2)
```

The `:nth-child` pseudoclass can also select repeating patterns of elements, such as all even or odd childs.

jQuery additionally offers the nonstandard `:eq(…)` pseudoclass for indexing, which you should probably use in this case:

```javascript
$("#accordion li:eq(1)")  // zero-based indexing
```

Further reading:

- [`:nth-child` CSS documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)
- [`:nth-child` jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)
- [`:eq` jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

In this mode you can count number of elements.

for example you have this :

```
<ul id="someId">
     <li>t1</li>
     <li>t2</li>
     <li>t1</li>
</ul>
```

the you can use `length` to count lis

```
var ln =$("#someId li").length;
```

after that find middle of length by this code

```
ln = ln / 2;
```

then use eq function of jquery to select middle Item like this

```
$("#someId li:eq("+ln+")").css("border","1px solid red");
```

But don't forget indexing by using eq starts from 0 .
I hope my answer help you :)

Comment: jQuery also has an [`eq` method](https://api.jquery.com/eq/). Therefore, we could write that example more clearly as `var $items = $("#someId li"); $items.eq($items.length / 2).css("border","1px solid red");`

Comment: Of course buddy, But my explanation was educational and amateur .

Answer (score 0):

Another way to select second element is to use [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) `+`:

```
$("#accordion li:first + li")
```

Here is a demo.

```js
$("#accordion li:first + li").addClass('selected');
```

```css
.selected {color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="accordion">
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

And here is also generic solution for arbitrary number of `li` elements (not only 3):

```js
$('#accordion li ~ li:not(:last)').addClass('selected');
```

```css
.selected {color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="accordion">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer his question

Comment: Yes it does: *"I have three <li> tags"* and *"How can I select the middle <li>?"*.